# Maths calculation: Compare coordinates to make reasonable shape

Tags: java, math

i have a mathematical problem. Im making a game where the user is a 12 year old kid. The child's goal is to calculate the area of a drawn shape. In easy and medium mode, the shapes are given and hard coded so they are not hardcore. in the hard mode 5 coordinates are randomly generated and here is where the problem comes. I need to make a shape which area is calculable by a 12 y/o child. With the random coordinates come various hard things, such as intersections, or odd points on a line connecting 2 other points and so. Is there any way to calculate and avoid such problems?

Here is my code which makes the random points + draws it on a dot grid in the application:

```
private void gameHard ()
{
    //distance between points is 65 pixels, the numbers that are generated are 1-8
    x1=(genRandomInt())*65;
    x2=(genRandomInt())*65;
    x3=(genRandomInt())*65;
    x4=(genRandomInt())*65;
    x5=(genRandomInt())*65;
    y1=(genRandomInt())*65;
    y2=(genRandomInt())*65;
    y3=(genRandomInt())*65;
    y4=(genRandomInt())*65;
    y5=(genRandomInt())*65;

    compareRCoordinates ();

    areaImage = new JPanel ()
      {  
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.fillRect(0,0,780,650);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            int xnum = 65, ynum = 65;   
            for(ynum=65;ynum<650;ynum=ynum+65)
            {
                int x=0, y=0;
                for(xnum = 65;xnum<780;xnum=xnum+65)
                {
                x = xnum-9;
                y = ynum-9;     
                g2.fillOval(x,y,18,18);

            }
            xnum=xnum+65;
            }
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
            g2.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            g2.drawLine(x2,y2,x3,y3);
            g2.drawLine(x3,y3,x4,y4);
            g2.drawLine(x4,y4,x5,y5);
            g2.drawLine(x5,y5,x1,y1);
        }
    };

    areaImage.setBounds(20,20,780,650);
    areaImage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    this.add(areaImage);
    roundsPlayed++;
}
```

Comment: What kinds of shapes are you planning to include? Is it always rectangles? Parallelograms, trapezoids, rhombuses? Triangles? Circles? Or do you want any convex or concave shape with five coordinates for this hard mode?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238608/randomly-generating-a-shape for examples of simple random shapes using Java2D

Comment: @mbomb007 in general any shape made of 5 points ;)

Comment: So you mean pentagons?  Did you read [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html)?

Comment: if you are looking for an easy-peasy solution to a problem that is difficult you are looking for some ready-made soup - thats not what we do here

Answer (score 2):

Here's the outline of a fairly straightforward method.

- Choose five distinct random points.
- Calculate the centroid of the five points (that is, the average X co-ordinate and the average Y co-ordinate).
- Calculate the angle from the centroid to each of the five original points.  If one of the points happens to be the centroid, then pick any number at all (such as 0) as the angle.
- Arrange the points in order of the angle calculated.  Ties can be broken arbitrarily.

OK, the points now make a pentagon in the order you've arranged them (including a line segment from the last point to the first one).  It's not necessarily convex, but it won't have any "crossing over".  You can draw this on the screen.

And you can calculate the area as

```
( x1 * y2 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y4 + x4 * y5 + x5 * y1 - y1 * x2 - y2 * x3 - y3 * x4  - y4 * x5 - y5 * x1 ) / 2
```

Comment: Nice. Upvoted. There is a rare corner case if three (or more) points happen to have the same angle. This may be solved, for instance, by breaking ties by the distance from the centroid.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. I  didn't think of that particular corner case.

Answer (score 0):

My basic idea is I divide your 64 (8 by 8) possible points into 5 disjoint rectangular areas and pick one random point from each area. The areas are picked so that connecting the points in order will never cause any connecting lines to cross. It’s quite simple — maybe too simple?

```
    x1 = genRandomInt(1, 3) * 65;
    y1 = genRandomInt(1, 4) * 65;
    x2 = genRandomInt(1, 3) * 65;
    y2 = genRandomInt(5, 8) * 65;
    x3 = genRandomInt(4, 8) * 65;
    y3 = genRandomInt(6, 8) * 65;
    x4 = genRandomInt(4, 8) * 65;
    y4 = genRandomInt(4, 5) * 65;
    x5 = genRandomInt(6, 8) * 65;
    y5 = genRandomInt(1, 3) * 65;
```

Write `genRandomInt(int from, int to)` so that it returns a random int in the interval from `from` through `to` inclusive. In the code above I have between 10 and 15 possible points in each of the rectangular areas.

Comment: actually its 10 by 8, but  get the point... might do the work if i dont find something mathematical to calculate. ;)

Comment: OK. The banal generalization would take areas that are 5 points high instead of 4 in the left side, and 3, 4 and 3 high instead of 3, 2 and 3 in the right side. However, I’m afraid that these picks of areas will make it possible for lines to cross so you don’t get a proper pentagon. So you may have to do a little playing around with the boundaries to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays for the coordinates facilitates.

One could use a random distance to the prior points so points are not near. I'll be math lazy and simply repeat selecting new random numbers till the random point is no longer near.

Finally I cheat and use `java.awt.Polygon` to check that the new candidate point is not inside the polygon till that.

Polygon one can draw, and even fill.

The fields:

```
int[] xs = new int[5]; // xs[0] till xs[4]
int[] ys = new int[5];
Polygon pentagon;
```

Picking random points:

```
final int NEAR = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    // Pull random numbers for this i'th point till okay.
    for (;;) {
        xs[i] = random ...
        ys[i] = random ...

        // Check that the point is not inside the polygon till now:
        if (i >= 3) {
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xs, ys, i);
            if (polygon.contains(xs[i], ys[i]) {
                continue; // Inside
            }
        }

        // Check that the point are apart:
        boolean near = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i && !near; ++j) {
            near = Math.abs(xs[i] - xs[j]) < NEAR
                && Math.abs(ys[i] - ys[j]) < NEAR;
        }
        if (near) {
            continue; // Too near
        }

        break; // Found point i
    } 
}
pentagon = new Polygon(xs, ys, 5);
```

Drawing:

```
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
        g2.draw(pentagon);

        g2.setColor(Color.TEAL);
        g2.fill(pentagon);
        ... draw grid
```

As you might image there might be sufficient looping. Endless when the first four points cover the largest part of the screen.

Comment: Your test that the point is not inside the polygon drawn until now, is that sound? For a concave pentagon, the last point could be inside. On the other hand, you may get crossing edges even though the point is outside, for example (100, 100), (200, 200), (200, 100), (100, 200).

Comment: @OleV.V. I think the polygon's contains method is clever enough for concave ones. You are right to be suspicious though. There is something I did not do however: **if a point "outside" is found, it must not simply added at the end but between points (i, i+1%n), where the distances are minimal.**  Or such. - _some programming required._

Comment: @OleV.V. as you gave an answer: I did not want to give take-away answer, as I think it must be some course material, and hence knowlegde should be there. Only the programming should be refined: approach, using array, Polygon.

Comment: The idea of sorting the points by distance can be taken a step further if one likes. Just pick 5 points at random as in the question. Apply one of the [Travelling salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution) algorithms to determine their order in the polygon. It doesn’t need to be an exact algorithm as long is it makes sure there are no crossing edges.

Comment: Indeed, for 5 an NP solution is fine.